# Azure Devops Ubuntu 18.04 angular e2e tests

Tags: angular, azure-devops, protractor, e2e-testing

The latest version of chrome installed on the Ubuntu 18.04 build agents is listed [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md).  I'm attempting to use `81.0.4044.138` at the time of this writing.

In my package.json I have the following scripts:

```js
{
  ...
  scripts: {
    ...
    "ci-e2e": "ng e2e --protractor-config e2e/ci.protractor.conf.js --webdriver-update=false",
    "webdriver-update": "./node_modules/.bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome=81.0.4044.138",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I am running `webdriver-update` followed by `ci-e2e` in my pipeline:

[image]

I keep getting this error in my Azure DevOps pipeline:

```sh
...
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5713000Z [18:29:30] E/launcher - session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5713844Z   (Driver info: chromedriver=81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}),platform=Linux 5.3.0-1022-azure x86_64)
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5714690Z [18:29:30] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5715686Z   (Driver info: chromedriver=81.0.4044.69 (6813546031a4bc83f717a2ef7cd4ac6ec1199132-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#776}),platform=Linux 5.3.0-1022-azure x86_64)
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5716525Z     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5717285Z     at parseHttpResponse (/home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5718469Z     at /home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5718928Z     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5719422Z From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5720072Z     at Function.createSession (/home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5720820Z     at Function.createSession (/home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5721779Z     at Direct.getNewDriver (/home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5722537Z     at Runner.createBrowser (/home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5723198Z     at /home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5723892Z     at _fulfilled (/home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5724550Z     at /home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5725293Z     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5726001Z     at /home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
2020-05-27T18:29:30.5726677Z     at runSingle (/home/vsts/work/1/s/wheres-my-order/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
...
```

It keeps trying to use `81.0.4044.69` instead of `81.0.4044.138` like I've specified.

I've even added this to my `ci.protractor.conf.js`:

```js
    ...
    chromeDriver: '../node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_81.0.4044.138',
    ...
```

I'm really struggling with the e2e suite.  Everytime the Azure Devops agents get released, I have to go and specify this magic version number that isn't the latest, but the latest from the agent's perspective and I'd really like to set this up so that I don't have to keep going back and pushing code changes every time the version I have to use changes.  Is there a way to do this without hard coding the version number?

Answer (score 0):

Accodring to [ubuntu-18.04 release note](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md):

> ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138 (8c6c7ba89cc9453625af54f11fd83179e23450fa-refs/branch-heads/4044@{#999}); Chrome Driver is available via CHROMEWEBDRIVER environment variable

The ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.138 has been installed in the Path $(CHROMEWEBDRIVER).

Note: $(CHROMEWEBDRIVER) is equal to

```
/usr/local/share/chrome_driver
```

Based on my test, I use the "PowerShell Script" task to output the ChromeDriver and Chrome version.

```
google-chrome --version

cd $(CHROMEWEBDRIVER)
chromedriver --version
```

Result:

[image: Script Result]

You could run these script to check the version of chrome and chromedriver.

Then you could try to directly use the path of the chromedriver from Ubuntu 18.04 agent.

I refer to the @amirated suggestion on [this tiket](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/issues/342#issuecomment-536203981) .

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use this environment variable to specify where chrome driver is for the e2e tests in protractor.conf.js. I got it working again with puppeteer but I really didn't like that solution since I felt like it should have been just as easy to do it without puppeteer.

Comment: I'll try this again, but I'll be guessing how to use that environment variable

Comment: This may not be a good method, but it can make sure that the chrome version you are using is 81.0.4044.138.  $(CHROMEWEBDRIVER) is equals to `/usr/local/share/chrome_driver`. You could try to point to this path: `/usr/local/share/chrome_driver/Chrome version...` .